# how to add number which is increment for the same name using jquery

Tags: jquery

In a page i am showing the name in a particular format. Now i have to add the incremental number like 1,2,... etc.,
The name format like as follows,

```
var timeStamp= new Date(panelGrid.SubmissionVersion.substring(8, panelGrid.Version.length));
        var timeStamp= (kendo.toString(timeStamp, "yyyyMMMdd"));
        var obj = '.accordion-sub-hd:eq(0)';
        //$('.accordion-sub-hd i').before(Name+ '-' + timeStamp);
        $(obj).find('i.placement_name').html('SUB -' + Name +' -'+timeStamp);
```

The Result is SUB-xxxx-2016Jul20

If the date is same date for multiple names, it should be come by incremental order.

Expected Result is SUB-xxxx1-2016Jul20

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a global variable to store the count. Initialise it once during declaration:

```
var count = 1;
```

Then use the count within the name and increment it every time it is being used:

```
$(obj).find('i.placement_name').html('SUB -' + Name + count +' -'+timeStamp);
count++;
```

That way you always keep the value stored inside count and when you want to reset the counter you just set it back to 0.

If you want, you can store the previous timestamp as well and do a check to set the count back to 1 when the previous used timestamp is not equals to the current timestamp. That way you would always have the count starting from 1 for each different timestamp.